# CUPS: use printers in different subnet

Tags: cups, printer, subnets

I am trying to configure a cups server located in a subnet, that have to comunicate with printers installed in others subnets.

For example:
cups server ip:      192.168.0.1 /16
printer 01 ip:       192.168.1.10/16
printer 02 ip:       192.168.2.10/16
(and so on)

The cups server is installed on a Debian server, and from this server I am able to ping all the printers.
I have installed the printers with lpd protocol (like many others times with that machines) but when I launch a print job, the error_log file tell me that the printer is unreachable.
I suspect that I need to modify the /etc/cups/cupsd.conf file, but I can't find out the right option.

Someone can help me?